# Different navbar styles when on mobile or desktop

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, desktop

Is there a way to change the navigation bars according to their viewports?

For example, when your viewport is ***1024x768*** you're gonna show the first navigation bar which built for desktop sizes and more, but if your viewport is lower than that resolution, display the '*mobile-friendly*' navigation bar.

Comment: look up CSS media queries.

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Media Queries:

In CSS:

```
@media (min-width:768px) and (min-height:1024px) {
 /*Desktop css*/
}
@media (max-width:768px) and (max-height:1024px) {
 /*Mobile css*/
}
```

Or with external stylesheets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width:768px) and (min-height:1024px)" href="desktop.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width:768px) and (max-height:1024px)" href="mobile.css">
```